# Working with adress of a pointer in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers

I have a function which receives an address of a pointer to an array, I want the function to iterate that array, how exactly should I write the function's code?

example of the function, and the function's call:

```
int example(int** arr, int n){}


k = example(&arr, n);
```

Using `*arr`, gives me the address of the first object in the array, using `**arr` gives me the value of the first object in the array.
But how do I access the next objects of the array is what I'm struggling with, let's say I want to iterate through the array in a for loop for example.

Comment: `(*arr)[i]`....

Comment: @Roman How is the array declared?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat did solve it for me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the array is just a dynamic array of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just treat `*arr` as an array

```
int *array = *arr;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // do something with array[i];
}
```